# Boots to GRUB and then won't start Ubuntu 17.10 except from in recovery mode

Tags: grub2, gnome, 17.10, reboot

It never used to boot to the GRUB menu and then last week it crashed while playing a youtube video and then restarted to the GRUB and got into a reboot cycle. I saw that it was flashing something when I tried booting into the Ubuntu option but it was for such a short time that I only managed to get it on one frame when recording with my gopro at 120fps. Error message as follows:

[0.072536] mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 4: fe00000000070f0f 
[0.072575] mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR d08de700 MISC c012000001808000 
[0.072612] mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 2:600f20 TIME 1516651435 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 600084f

Any help would be amazing! I'm booting into Recovery Mode at the moment but as such I can't us any digital painting software with reasonable performance, let alone try and stream it! This is making it tricky to do my uni work.

Incidentally, fans sound normal and checking the temperatures returns this: 
k10temp-pci-00c3 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
temp1:        +35.0°C  (high = +70.0°C) 
                       (crit = +80.0°C, hyst = +77.0°C) 
 
fam15h_power-pci-00c4 
Adapter: PCI adapter 
power1:       46.60 W  (crit = 125.19 W)

Hardware is:
CPU: AMD® Fx(tm)-8350 eight-core processor × 8 
GPU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn XT [Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition]
Boot drive: Kingston 120GB ssd
HDD: "ST31500541AS (CC35)" 1.5TB

Comment: What happens if you try to boot into a live usb?

Comment: It won't boot and then it reboots to grub so I selected the default ubuntu option again and I got the same error report  (although this time the error message lasted longer)

Comment: That's when booting a live usb flashed with a recent ISO?

Comment: No I think it's actually got 17.04 on it from when I last did a full rebuild

Comment: If you just started having the issue and it happens on a known working USB then it sounds like a hardware issue has reared its ugly head. Has anything happened to the hardware that could have caused anything? This would include a period of extreme dryness or moisture (and swings between them,) weird power cycles or surges, or kicking/knocking the case somehow. Does it work if you try another usb (maybe windows even?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was thermal damage to my GPU. Replaced the card and I still get the error code briefly but otherwise it boot normally.